Rust public abi for foreign language ffi
I'm writing a language and want it to be binary compatible with rust, c++ and some other languages. The problem is that I couldn't find information on rusts abi (name mangling, struct layouts, calling conventions, etc.).
I heard somewhere rust doesn't have a stable public abi (yet). But I couldn't find a source for that statement. I want to strictly avoid the c abi if possible.

source: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/600#issuecomment-526033825

You want an ABI that is compatible with C++ (and some other languages) but want to strictly avoid the C ABI?  What single ABI do you imagine will be supported across all these languages/compilers, if not the de-facto lingua-franca ABI of C?

Authoritative source for Rust data layout being (mostly) not publicly defined: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/type-layout.html#the-rust-representation.  Annoyingly I can't find any similar statement about the Rust calling convention, but I assure you that it is indeed also not publicly defined.

I don't imagine a single abi. I want my language to adapt based on the requested ffi language. So I have a extern "" syntax that makes the function use the given abi. But as true equals false linked this currently seems impossible as rust has no public abi I could support.

Rust has support for other ABIs, including the C ABI.  There is ongoing work for a more full-featured ABI built atop of the C ABI: crabi.  There are also third-party crates that provide more fuller featured ABI stability atop of the C ABI.

Rust indeed does not have a stable ABI, so you cannot be compatible with it.
Sources:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-layout.html#the-rust-representation, about type layout:

The Rust Representation
...
There are no other guarantees of data layout made by this representation.

https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/600#issuecomment-526033825

There are no current plans to introduce anything resembling a wholesale stable ABI either for some new repr(v1) or repr(Rust) and there is active opposition to this within the language team. As such, I'm going to close this super broad wishlist issue.

Name mangling actually is defined, although not for the old, currently used by default version, but for v0 (can be used with -C symbol-mangling-version=v0). See here about it.
There is an effort for "stable, but more high-level than the C ABI" ABI, currently called crabi, with other languages possibly integrating it as well. However, as of now it isn't even implemented experimentally even in Rust, so there is a long road ahead even if this experiment will succeed.
